# In $\mathbb{Z}$, find all generators of the subgroup $\langle 3\rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have an answer that says the generators of this subgroup are $\{3, -3\}$, but I do not understand why $-3$ is in it. Is $\langle 3\rangle$ not the set of all $3^n$, where $n$ is an integer? Why would Then the two sets would be $\langle 3\rangle =\{1, 3, 9, 27,\ldots\}$ and $\langle -3\rangle = \{1, -3, 9, -27,\ldots\}$, which are not the same, so it seems to me that $\langle 3\rangle\neq\langle -3\rangle$.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are using the wrong operation.

Comment: In light of C. Falcon's answer, notice that if another $x \in \langle 3 \rangle$ generated this subgroup, then in particular we'd need to be able to construct a sum that looks like $x + x + \cdots + x = 3$

Comment: Also, even if $\times$ was the operation, you forgot things like $\frac{1}{3} \in \langle 3 \rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a group when endowed with $+$, not $\times$. In particular, one has:
$$\langle 3\rangle=3\mathbb{Z}:=\{3n;n\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$$